# Can I put a button on the tab header using Firefox Add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In a Firefox browser window, I would like to put a button on the tab header next to the web page title. Is this possible with a Firefox add-on? So far I am still unsure what to call this part of a tab. Sorry for duplicates!

Edit: I didn't have the reputation to add images. [Here it is just for clarity (desired button in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHmqL.png)

Comment: This addon does exactly what you are trying for: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-badge/?src=search once installed get [DOMInspector Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) and [Element Inspector Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/) and then shift+right click on the tab badge, you'll see how the guy inlaid it, and its just like @Mayken described below.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly where I want to put the button. Thanks for sending me on the right track!

Comment: Awesome Sean, what is your plans for this addon btw? Just curious.

Comment: I wanted to learn how to make an add on and had a simple idea to add a button that preselects some text on the tab when you switch to it. I will put my code on github. thanks!

Comment: Awesome keep me updated! :) If you need help with first addon let me know I can walk you through (i have templates) it on irc im on #extdev, #introduction, #jsctypes and a bunch more https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is: "Yes."

Firefox add-ons have the ability to have almost complete control of the user interface. In this instance, the first level of XUL content that you would want to look at is contained in `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`. This file is contained within the `omni.ja` archive in the browser directory within the Firefox release directory.  All the `omni.ja` files are zip archives which you can view by extracting the files using a program that understands `.zip` archives. Depending on your OS, it may be easier to change the extension to `omni.zip`. Within that archive this file is `chrome\browser\content\browser\browser.xul`.

However the content that you would actually need to modify is located in the `chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml` file (in the same directory). This files defines what the tab stack looks like. How you go about changing this will depend on the type of add-on you are creating (e.g. overlay, restartless, add-on SDK) and if you want this change to apply to all tabs, or just some.

You will probably also want to look at `browser.css` which will be in a subdirectory of the `skin` directory.

The XUL structure for this element normally looks like:
[image: Tab XUL structure]

The `hbox` with `class="tab-content"` is most likely what you will want to modify.

In `tabbrowser.xml` it is currently (Firefox 38.0.5) defined as:

```
<xul:hbox xbl:inherits="pinned,selected,titlechanged"
          class="tab-content" align="center">
  <xul:image xbl:inherits="fadein,pinned,busy,progress,selected"
             class="tab-throbber"
             role="presentation"
             layer="true" />
  <xul:image xbl:inherits="src=image,fadein,pinned,selected,busy,crashed"
             anonid="tab-icon-image"
             class="tab-icon-image"
             validate="never"
             role="presentation"/>
  <xul:image xbl:inherits="crashed,busy"
             class="tab-icon-overlay"
             role="presentation"/>
  <xul:label flex="1"
             anonid="tab-label"
             xbl:inherits="value=visibleLabel,crop,accesskey,fadein,pinned,selected"
             class="tab-text tab-label"
             role="presentation"/>
  <xul:toolbarbutton anonid="close-button"
                     xbl:inherits="fadein,pinned,selected"
                     class="tab-close-button close-icon"/>
</xul:hbox>
```

Comment: In depth reply! Awesome!